# Я не понял систему очереди проверок

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

Вот [ссылка на очередь проверок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/197017) и вопрос. Откуда я мог знать, что этот человек скопипастил часть ответа, если другие ответы не отображаются?

Comment: Ниоткуда (хотя под этим ответом был соответствующий комментарий). Жалуйтесь на такие ответы модераторам (лучше тревогой на ответе), их уберут из очереди

Comment: Ничего страшного в одной проваленной проверке нет. В проверках вас не забанят )

Comment: Видим комментарий -> переходим к вопросу -> видим, что действительно скопипащен (или видим, что ответ уже удален) -> возвращаемся к проверке -> отмечаем, что нужно удалить. Я так и делаю в непонятных ситуациях.

Comment: @PashaPash, вот я думаю что не стоит удалять из очереди. Если бы проверка была реальной, то как раз нужно было понять, что это копипаста (текст какой-то как будто вырванный из контекста, ну и прочитать комментарий в конце концов).

Comment: По-моему, конец ответа выдаёт в нём спам просто с головой. Так что вас вполне справедливо завалило, я считаю. Но это вовсе не плохо. Вы совершенствуетесь потихоньку :)